# Is it good to have multiple media queries in CSS and because of this browser rendering will be affected?

Tags: css, responsive-design

So my question is related to media queries. I want to know by using multiple media queries will affect browser rendering speed or it's fine to use any number of media queries?

Answer (score 1):

You can use any number of media queries based on the device design and layout you are working on.

It won't affect on rendering speed on browser if your CSS is not much big in size.

Also make sure you don't duplicate the media query. Keep common things out of media query and only write css for things that change when the layout changes inside the media query.

Comment: I'm using webpack 3 with react.js so our plan was to write css individually for each component so there will be duplication of media quarries. So this practice is good or not good?

Comment: If all components or many component load on 1 particular page. You might have all CSS loading at same time having too many duplicate media quires, which will affect badly.

Comment: If you have very few components loading for 1 particular page it won't matter much.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn’t matter if you use one big or multiple media-queries in your code assuming your values are mostly the same. It shouldn’t matter if your values are different for each(!) of your hundreds of media-queries but could affect performance (found no way to track this down).

You can refer the same here : https://helloanselm.com/2014/web-performance-one-or-thousand-media-queries/